# angularjs render the code what I didn't want to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, turbolinks

I have a page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    {{hello}}
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var siteApp = angular.module('siteApp',[])
      angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['siteApp'])
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I run the page,I see nothing,because angular render the `{{hello}}`,but I just want to see `{{hello}}` how can I  realize this? and I can't use  `<html ng-app="siteApp">`,because I use `turbolinks`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the [`bootstrap`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) like this,

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['siteApp']);
});
```

**or**

```
angular.element(document.body).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['siteApp']);
});
```

here is a [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/gzRxZs4Kb1aaZtTpUCiW?p=preview)

and note that your trying to interpolate the `{{ hello }}` this will search `hello` variable in the scope, since there is no scope variable called `hello` it will print nothing, to check whether angular setup correctly use `{{ "hello" }}` this will print the hello since we are trying to print a string not a variable value.

**update**

you can change the interpolation delimiter to do this

EX:

```
var siteApp = angular.module('siteApp', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
});
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/iNenHw083T2NoGUErFMy?p=preview)

**to use in one place**

there is a angular built in directive called [`ng-non-bindable`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/docs/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable)

this directive will do this for you :)

```
<pre ng-non-bindable>{{hello}}</pre>
```

here is a [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/4NmJVNEuB9Lff7Q8OhX3?p=preview)

Comment: thanks for your answer,my question is how to stop angular to render the `{{hello}}` code,just show it .

Comment: if I place the `{{hello}}` into `<pre></pre>` I just want to show this itself, but angular will render this to nothing

Comment: so my mean is don't let angular render the `{{}}`tag in `<pre>`

Comment: good,but this will make all my `{{}}` not work,I just want to make the `{{}}` in `<pre>` to stay itself,can you realize this? thanks

Comment: think in this scene,user publish a article in my site,which include code like `<pre>{{....}}</pre>`.Of course I can't let angular render this

Comment: oowee oky you need it only in one place ok ill update please check,